# Where is Interactive JavaScript console - HDInsight

Tags: javascript, console, cluster-computing, interactive, azure-hdinsight

I can't find in my cluster manager the option "Interactive JavaScript console". How can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

This console no longer exists. It was removed from the service late last year. Your best bet for an alternative is probably powershell.